# What's the best way to get options Active Storage variant from db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eval, rails-activestorage

I need to get a options ( for example, resize_to_limit: [300, 222], kuwahara: '3%' ) of variant Active Storage (Ruby on Rails 6.1) from the db.
My decision:

app/admin/slideshow.rb

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Slideshow' do
  f.input :name
  f.input :options,
          input_html: { value: f.object.options || "{ resize_to_limit: [300, 222], kuwahara: '3%' }" },
          label: 'Options. For example: { resize_to_limit: [300, 222], monochrome: true }'
  f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
  end
  f.actions
end
```

app/controllers/slideshow_controllers.rb

```
  def options
   @options = proc {
   $SAFE = 1
   eval(Slideshow.take.options) if slideshow
}.call
  end

  def slideshow
   Slideshow.published.take
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% if slideshow_present? %>
    <% @slideshow.images.each do |x| %>
        <a href="<%= path_to_file(x) %>" data-lightbox="photo" class="col-sm-4">
        <%= image_tag x.variant(@options),
                :class => "img-fluid" %>
        </a>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

app/helpers/slideshows_helper.rb

```
  def path_to_file(x)
   Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(x, only_path: true)
  end
```

But I think using **eval** is not the best way to go. Perhaps you can recommend the best solution for me?

P.S. Is it advisable to use Ruby safe levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple...

app/admin/slideshow.rb

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Slideshow' do
      f.input :name
      f.input :options,
              input_html: { value: f.object.options || '{ "resize_to_limit": [300, 222], "kuwahara": "3%", "quality": 15 }' },
              label: 'Options. For example: { "resize_to_limit": [300, 222], "monochrome": true }'
      f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

app/controllers/slideshow_controllers.rb

```
  def options
    #     @options = proc {
    #       $SAFE = 1
    #       eval(Slideshow.take.options) if slideshow
    #     }.call
    @options = JSON.parse(Slideshow.take.options) if slideshow
  end
```

[For example](https://github.com/cmirnow/CRUD-Blog/blob/master/app/controllers/slideshows_controller.rb#L21)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understand your goal, but you can access some helpful info in two different ways.

Let's say you've predefined some variants in your model:

```rb
has_many_attached :files do |attachable|
  attachable.variant :small, resize_to_limit: [375, nil], format: :webp
  attachable.variant :medium, resize_to_limit: [1400, nil], format: :webp
  attachable.variant :large, resize_to_limit: [1600, nil], format: :webp
end
```

Then you access a variant derived from the original attachment (I'll call it `file`):

```rb
varient = file.variant(:small)
```

### 1) Metadata

```rb
variant.image.metadata
#=> {{"identified"=>true, "width"=>375, "height"=>319, "analyzed"=>true}}
```

That might have some of the info you need, but it looks like you might be after the transformation info.

### 2) Transformations

```rb
variant.variation.transformations
#=> {:format=>:webp, :resize_to_limit=>[375, nil]}
```

#### Small Gotcha...

Rails will process variants lazily. That means `metadata` won't be available until it's processed the first time. Check out the [variant docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html) for more. I'll warn you, it gets a little nasty when you start forcing processing (lots of database activity). I hope these options are helpful.